# DOAJ XML upload automatically using nodejs

Tags: node.js, xml

I require an endpoint for XML uploads in DOAJ. Currently, I'm manually uploading files through the website, but I want to automate the process using Node.js

I checked in DOAJ api , Here xml manual update details only parent

Comment: You need to send an HTTP Post.  Any programming language will work.  Here is the format of the xml which will be the same if you manually uploaded the file : https://doaj.org/docs/xml/  Here is the format of the HTTP Request (post) :  https://doaj.org/api/v3/docs

Comment: I tried https://doaj.org/api/articles?api_key=Xnnx this url but here parameters should be json format. I need XML file upload api. Help on this

Comment: I assume the link in your last comment was the response from server which is json.  The only thing that needs to be XML is the body of the Request.  The content type in the request has to be set to xml and the body needs to be xml.  Try reading through documentation and did not find an example.  I don't want to give an answer that I'm not sure of the syntax.  I would contact the developers.